# DMax to generate a new Unique ID

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form in access that adds a new record into a table. I use DMax + 1 to get a new ID but is there a way to differentiate the different types of ID in a table?
I want to add the words PHS before the number. For example I want the ID to look like PHS001 etc.

```
Me.txtPATS.Value =  DMax("PATS_ActionID", "tblPAT3") + 1
```

Comment: As in `"PHS" & DMax("PATS_ActionID", "tblPAT3") + 1`?

Comment: @KostasK.  I tried that but I keep getting a type mismatch error

Comment: Then, most likely, `PATS_ActionID` is a number. It must be text for that to work.

Comment: Probably because there are no records in the table and the DMax returns null. Try `"PHS" & Nz(DMax("PATS_ActionID", "tblPAT3"), 0) + 1`

Comment: @Gustav I though VBA can handle string/numeric concatenation by silently converting the number to a string?

Comment: @KostasK.: Indeed, but you can't save such values to a numeric field.

Comment: @KostasK.  PATS_ActionID is a short text.

Comment: DMax is not very efficient with text (if not at all). I would suggest to change the ID to an auto-number (let it populate itself) and format the id only on presentation. Besides, most  form-controls for an ID are read-only (you don't really edit an id) so you could easily concatenate it in your query: `"PHS" & [PATS_ActionID]`.

Answer (score 0):

That could be like:

```vb
Me!txtPATS.Value = "PHS" & CStr(DMax("PATS_ActionID", "tblPAT3", "[PATS_ActionID] Like 'PHS*'") + 1))
```